# Shouldn't the infinite sea of electrons contribute to gravity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, dirac-equation, cosmological-constant

According to my understanding of the dirac equation, there's an infinite sea of electrons occupying all negative energy states which prevents an electron from dropping to lower and lower energy states down to negative infinity.

Since these are electrons, they have obviously have a charge, and hence every electron sits in the potential of every other: essentially there is a collosal amount of energy in all of space from these sea electrons.

Shouldn't this energy contribute to gravity? I understand that the cosmological constant should be energy present at all points in space, which causes space to expand. Wouldn't this energy do the same?

Comment: Yup, it does, and it contribute negatively. That’s why exact supersymmetry would give us zero vacuum energy, the fermions would cancel out the bosons.

Comment: The "Dirac sea" is an obsolete concept. Now that we have a proper understanding of quantum field theory, it is not necessary anymore. To be clear: the modern paradigm does not include the Dirac sea as one of its ingredients. See also https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/309972/84967, https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/315603/84967.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform As usual I have to disagree. The Dirac sea is a perfectly self-consistent story that provides valuable intuition. Only a purist would categorically reject it!

Comment: @knzhou Eh, I never said it was inconsistent; only that it is useless. And it is. There is not a single concept that is easier to understand using the Dirac sea. Everything you can explain with it, you can explain without. And it is not an intuitive/easy to accept concept, so why introduce it in the first place? As I said, it is not taken seriously nowadays; it lives on because of its historical significance.

Comment: @knzhou I mostly agree with AFT. The Dirac is a useful concept in solid-state physics, because it's a reasonably accurate picture of what's actually going on. But contrary to the popular lore, positrons and electron holes are *not* equivalent in the real world of relativistic QFT, because positrons (presumably) contribute positively to the stress-energy tensor of general relativity, and holes contribute negatively (relative to a uniform Dirac sea background).

Comment: Another issue with the Dirac sea story is that bosons can have antiparticles just as easily as fermions, but the Dirac sea can't explain bosonic antiparticles at all.

Comment: @tparker Actually, the Dirac sea story is totally different in RQFT and solid state. In solid state, as you said, holes are the absence of an electron, and since all electron states have positive energy the holes have negative energy. But in RQFT there exist negative frequency modes (which do _not_ exist in solid state because the Schrödinger equation is first-order in time but the Klein-Gordan equation is second-order) which means in the naive old picture they have negative energy. So a hole has positive energy. The similarity between the two stories is just superficial.

Comment: I do agree with @AccidentalFourierTransform in that the Dirac sea is not necessary: it’s just words you would use to fix up the situation if you did the quantization naively. (Basically we define the creation and annihilation operators backward by accident, get the wrong vacuum state, and then put in the Dirac sea to get the right vacuum.) But I do think it’s useful for at least some intuition. How would you intuitively show the SUSY vacuum energy vanishes otherwise? And it’s the most naive thing to do if you’ve never quantized a fermionic field, so the most natural for first-time learners.

Comment: @knzhou Okay, I guess I'm not familiar enough with the relativistic version of the Dirac sea argument to comment intelligently. Re your last question, I would say that the vacuum energy has no physical content, so neither does its putative vanishing in SUSY. The apparently divergent vacuum energy in free scalar field theory merely results from an operator-ordering ambiguity in which classical Hamiltonian you choose to quantize, you can set it to any value you want (including zero) by simply ordering the operators appropriately.

Comment: @tparker I have to disagree, you can prove using the SUSY algebra alone that the vacuum energy vanishes. But now I’m confused, because as you said, the choice of quantization procedure affects the vacuum energy.

Comment: Note that the SUSY algebra is not invariant under $H\to H+c\boldsymbol 1$. Therefore, when writing the algebra one is already imposing an energy origin. In this case, the origin is at the vacuum state. Any ordering prescription for the bosons must be accompanied by the corresponding prescription for the fermions, for otherwise the "regulator" does not respect SUSY. Thus, the vacuum energy is insensitive to ordering ambiguities: whatever ordering you pick, the fermionic effect will cancel the bosonic effect, as required by the SUSY algebra. If it doesn't, you've broken SUSY.

Answer (score 1):

Do not confuse models with reality/data.

The hypothesis of infinite seas of electrons has been left behind because better mathematical models were developed, and the problems of real electrons in infinite seas are model problems.

The solutions of the Dirac equation described fermions for us and started the way to quantum field theory which is the present tool of studying particle physics.

In the [standard model of particle physics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model), all the  point elementary particles in the table cover all of space as fields, on which operators creating and annihilating the particles act. Thus charged massive  particles exist only where the creation operators act, the dirac model is not applicable. What is kept from the dirac equation is the plane wave solution for fermions,(the maxwell for photons,...) which represents the quantum  field of the particle at all points in space, i.e. the electron field  in your case.

The [vacuum expectation value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuum_expectation_value) for all these fields is zero, except for the Higgs boson.

(It is important to keep in mind that this is the quantum framework, where wavefunctions lead to probabilities of interaction, not certitudes.)

Comment: what is the reason for downvote? looks reasonable to me...

Comment: @IamAStudent  if you continue your studies in physics you will realize that there are people who have their own physics in mind, not mainstream. A down vote may also mean that I am not answering the question asked."if this is true should it not..." in a vague cosmological allusion. I am answering that this model is no longer valid, and do not bother with cosmological implications.