# Why does the SUSY vacuum energy vanish independently of the quantization scheme?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, vacuum, quantization

This question was inspired by the comments [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/422948/shouldnt-the-infinite-sea-of-electrons-contribute-to-gravity). It is straightforward to show that the SUSY vacuum energy vanishes, $H|0 \rangle = 0$, using nothing but the SUSY algebra. For people who prefer a less formal derivation, there's also an intuitive way to show this using the Dirac sea.

Every bosonic mode is quantized to a (bosonic) harmonic oscillator, which has a ground state energy of $\hbar \omega / 2$. Meanwhile, every fermionic mode is quantized to a fermionic harmonic oscillator. Now in general the modes come in pairs of positive and negative frequency $\pm \hbar \omega$, and the energy levels of a fermionic oscillator are
$$\text{frequency } \omega: \{0, \hbar \omega\}, \quad \text{frequency } {-}\omega: \{0, -\hbar\omega\}.$$
Therefore, in the ground state, the negative frequency mode is occupied, giving a Dirac sea, and we have a ground state energy of ${-}\hbar \omega$. By SUSY, bosonic and fermionic modes pair up, for a total ground state energy of
$$\frac{\hbar \omega}{2} + \frac{\hbar \omega}{2} - \hbar \omega = 0.$$
That's why the ground state energy vanishes in SUSY.

On the other hand, a purist would say that this calculation is completely bogus, because the vacuum energy of a quantum field is completely determined by the quantization prescription; we can make the vacuum energy zero by normal ordering the Hamiltonian, or more generally anything we want. The cancellation only works because I used a particular operator ordering, which in my opinion is the most "naive" and simple one.

But on the other other hand, we know that the vacuum energy *must* be zero in any quantization prescription that preserves SUSY, because we can prove it using only the SUSY algebra. So what is the SUSY vacuum energy -- is it zero or is it anything we want? If it's zero, why doesn't adjusting the operator ordering disrupt this? Does it necessarily break SUSY?

Comment: Please explain why you think vanishing vacuum energy follows from the SUSY algebra. Adding an arbitrary constant to the Hamiltonian generator doesn’t change any of the commutator laws, and $H$ doesn’t participate in anticommutators because it is grassman-even. Adding any constant shift to the definition of energy would still preserve the algebra, or am I wrong?

Comment: @SolenodonParadoxus That’s wrong. The anticommutator you use is $\{Q, Q\} = H$, which is not preserved upon adding a constant to $H$. The full proof is about two lines long and I’ll type it out for you later!